# Run time optimisation of Pentaho PDI transformation

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I'm running this transformation in PDI and it took me hours to load table that contains 18000 record .

[image]

SQL query in the iput table step :
[image]

Is it normal or should I try to optimize the SQL query or add more steps ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your sql code is not effective. You should not to cast column, and should cast the parameter only. Sometimes, cast column is so expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's your output step that is slow, not the input step.

Here's how you can check if that's the case:

1. Add a Dummy step between those two steps;
2. Disable the hop going OUT of the Dummy step;
3. Run the transformation.

It will now run just the read part, which should be reasonably fast. If that's the case, then it's your output step that is slow, not the input. You can also check by running the entire transformation and looking at the Input/Output value on the Step metrics. A slow step will have its input buffer full (meaning it's slower than the steps upstream) and an almost empty output buffer (slower than the steps downstream).

If you confirm it's indeed your input step that is slow: your query can't make any use of indexes, as the condition is rather complex. You may need to refactor it.

If the input step isn't the problem: the Insert/Update step is rather slow, as each row of data requires a round trip to lookup the keys before trying to either insert or update.

You can avoid that, to some extent, by doing the following:

1. Add a unique constraint on the keys in the output table;
2. Use a Table output step (which only inserts). Any rows that try to insert duplicate keys will error out.
3. Add an Update step after the table output. When connecting it, choose "Error handling of step" as the hop type.

With this:

- any new keys will be inserted by the Table output;
- any repeated keys will error out on Insert and will be sent to the Error handling hop;
- The update step will then update only the rows that need updating, without trying to figure out if they should be inserted or updated.

This can significantly boost your performance. But in any case, updating large volumes of data is more often than not a slow operation.